# Mongo gear not responding with update query fired

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, openshift

I have been trying to do run an update query on mean application of my own and everytime the update query is failing. The get and post are working fine. I have a MEAN app hosted on OpenShift using free account.

If anyone wants to look at the code I can add code... I am perplexed because the same code is working my localhost

The error I receive is following

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request PUT /rest/artists.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at dump-myartdb.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

Comment: Can you include the error messages that you are getting from your code, or in your application/database log files?

Comment: any help will be appreciated i Ma kind of stuck at this point with this weird issue.

Comment: It may also help posting your code that is used to create this PUT request + an example of what is sent when the error occurs. What is the key difference when compared with those GET and POST requests that do work?

Comment: I fixed the issue. The issue was that i was trying to send in object that had "_id" generated by mongodb and it assumed i wanted to edit that.

Comment: @user2461304, could you post this as an answer to your original question to have this one formally closed? Thanks.